# Why my internet connection gets discontented automatically

Tags: 20.04

I was windows user then I saw reviews about ubuntu performance and features then I decided to install ubuntu. I installed ubuntu 20.04 latest. Installation was successful but it has one weird problem. My wifi connection gets disconnected automatically then I try to connected again it takes several tries then it connect back after 2 to 4 min , but after using few minutes it gets disconnected again. I am really upset with this ubuntu error.
Can you help me to resolve this issue ?
Am using ubuntu 20.04
P.S: my networking information is following
Network controller: Ralink Corp. RT3290 wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

Comment: You should specify your license plate brand and model. Run the command lshw.

Comment: @Carlos Dagorret I executed lshw command it displayed long list of information.  What should I copy ? I dun find license

Comment: Just look under "network" for the model that the command lists. Then modify the post, with the model of your network card.
Another command you can use is lspci.

Comment: @Carlos Dagorret I have updated my question. Here is detail of my networking

Comment: Network controller: Ralink Corp. RT3290 wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

Comment: See this thread : https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/690368

Comment: @Carlos Dagorret his final solution is that "The ultimate solution is to by a new internal Wifi card which has official Linux driver available."

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: @waltinator I tried solutions but none is working. Do I need to uninstall linux or replace my wifi card? I read few articles where they are saying no official solution shared for rt3290 wifi drivers